# Getting comparisons using HElib?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make comparisons on ciphertexts.
Given two ciphertext `c1` and `c2` of two values `p1=p2 = 1`, instruction `c1 == c2` or `c1.equalsTo(c2)` always give `false`.
How can I solve this?

Is it possible to do a greater than comparison in the form `(c1 < c2)` on two ciphertexts?

Suppose I have two cipher texts `c1` and `c2` for the plain text `p1`,`p2` respectively how can I compare them using HElib any one provide me a source code or working logic?

Comment: suppose i have two cipher texts c1 and c2 for the plain text p1,p2 respectively how can i compare them using HElib any one provide me a sourse code or working logic ?

Comment: Start with telling us what types c1 and c2 are.

Comment: If it is cryptographically secure, then the ciphertext is (more or less) indistinguishable from random noise, so what is the point of comparison? If it is a deterministic cipher, then p1 == p2 implies that c1 == c2, which makes != relevant, but "less than" is not relevant. And if it is not deterministic, then != is also irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

No, in HElib it is not possible to directly compare two ciphertexts.

This is due to the cryptographic system used in HElib. However, even without going into detail on that it can be said that no public-key cryptosystem (HElib is public-key) could ever support an operation like `c1 < c2` that returns an unencrypted boolean since that would enable an attacker to easily find the plaintext of any ciphertext simply by encrypting new values and comparing.

If you want to do comparisons in HElib you need to represent your entire program as a binary circuit with individually encrypted bits. Then you can implement conditional branching as multiplexing. This is not only tedious but also in general too slow (HElib is not a fast encryption system) for any 'real' program.